# vim: replace a string with the "/" character in it

Tags: vim

I've been using the following to replace characters:

1. To find each occurrence of `eth0` in the current line only, and replace it with `br0`,enter (first press Esc key and type):

   ```
   :s/eth0/br0/g
   ```
2. To find and replace all occurrences of `eth1` with `br1`, enter:

   ```
   :%s/eth1/br1/g
   ```
3. To find and replace all occurrences of `eth1` with `br1`, but ask for confirmation first, enter:

   ```
   :%s/eth1/br1/gc
   ```
4. To find and replace all occurrences of case insensitive `eth1` with `br1`, enter:

   ```
   :%s/eth1/br1/gi
   ```

However, how would I replace a string with one that has a `/` in it. For example, I want 
to replace all my debug printf statements with `//`. When I type..

```
:%s/printf/ // /gc
```

it gives me a Trailing characters error. If someone could teach me how to do this i would be thankful.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a different separator:

```
:s+sprintf+ // +g
```

Answer (score 3):

escape the `/` in `:s/.../../` or better, use other separator:

e.g. `s:@...@...@g`